Can't Link animation between 2 objects
I imported a new version of a dress i made and i wanted to link the animation so i don't have to do it all again but when i link the dress it becomes giant and i cant scale it down because it always reset the scale.




It is not clear what's wrong in your screenshots. Is the scale 1 for both objects ?

The first picture is both dresses, and then the other 2 is what happends when i link the object animation. The second image u see is the one that has the animation. Its normal but the other one (image 3) gets scaled and i cant scale it down

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

I managed to find the problem. Basically it was because the origin of the dress wasnt centered to the geometry. Once i set the origin to the geometry the scale didnt change
